# Xamarin IOS push notification navigate to page

Tags: ios, xamarin, push-notification

I have push notification working great. On android I can navigate to the desired page when the user clicks the notification and the app launches. I can't figure out how to do the same thing on IOS. I am sure this is very standard but can't find any docs on this. One thing is this is a Shell App. I see some examples for navigation pages that I have tried and the equivalent does not seem to work. see below

### Things I have tried:

1. On android when the app launches it re runs `OnCreate` in MainActivity, so I can pass the relevant information to the APP and navigate as needed. On IOS `FinishedLaunching` is never called when the app pops up from a notification being clicked so this is not an option.
2. Within the notification handler `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` I tried running `Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EventsPage)}");` This seems to have no effect.
3. I tried MessagingCenter. So in my notification handler `MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this, "Hi");`. Then in

> ```
> public App()
> {
>      InitializeComponent();
>      MainPage = new AppShell();
>      MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi", (obj) =>
>      {
>            Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EventsPage)}");
>      });
> }
> ```

This fires fine, and GoToAsync fires but it has no effect.

4. I tried moving the subscription to the end of AppShell Constructor. But it never fires there.

Can anyone point me to an example of how one typically navigates to a shell page when the user clicks a background notification in Xamarin IOS? Or tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!!

Comment: Try `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EventsPage)}"));`

Comment: that was a good suggestion. Unfortunately no luck. I tried putting that directly in the notification callback as well as in the MessagingCenter.Subscribe. :-(

Comment: Wait. I tried all my pages, and there is one page that  it finally worked. Investigating to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IOS you need to specify a new tab or stack or whatever "//" refers to.
Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(EventsPage)}");

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
{
    
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(EventsPage)}");
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
}
```